# Wordpress using custom template for sub-sub-category and posts within

Tags: php, wordpress

There is a big common category `Catalog` (`$category->cat_ID = 2`). It contains a few sub-categories like `Series1`, `Series2` and so on. Every sub-category contains a few sub-sub-categories like `Type1`, `Type2`, etc. And every sub-sub-category contains some products (type `post`).
I don't need to show common category `Catalog` and its sub-categories, but I need to show sub-sub-category with its products on individual pages.
How to set `404.php` template for category `Catalog` and its sub-categories and custom templates for every sub-sub-categories (with list of products) and for every product?

I have found code below (`functions.php` file)

```
function catalog_template() {    
// Get the category id from global query variables
$cat = get_query_var('cat');

if(!empty($cat)) {    

    // Get the detailed category object
    $category = get_category($cat);

    // Check if it is sub-category and having a parent, also check if the template file exists
    if( ($category->parent != '0') && ($category->parent == '2') && (file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/catalog.php')) ) { 

        // Include the template for sub-catgeory
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/catalog.php');
        exit;
    }
    return;
}
return;

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'catalog_template');
```

but I don't know how to customize it for my needs.

**UPD.** I've written the code below

```
function catalog_template() {    
// Get the category id from global query variables
$cat = get_query_var('cat');

if(!empty($cat)) {    
    $catalog_id = get_cat_ID('Catalog');

    $catalog_child_cats = array();

        foreach(get_all_category_ids() as $child_cat)
        {
            if(get_category($child_cat)->parent==$catalog_id)
            {
                $catalog_child_cats[]=$child_cat;
            }
        }

    // Get the detailed category object
    $category = get_category($cat);
    $cat_parent_id = $category->cat_ID;

    // Check if it is sub-category and having a parent, also check if the template file exists
    if( (in_array($cat_parent_id, $catalog_child_cats)) && (file_exists(TEMPLATEPATH . '/catalog.php')) ) { 

        // Include the template for sub-sub-catgeory
        include(TEMPLATEPATH . '/catalog.php');
        exit;
    }
    return;
}
return;

}
add_action('template_redirect', 'catalog_template');
```

but it uses `catalog_template` for `sub-categories` too. How to set `404.php` for common category `Catalog` and for its sub-categories?

**UPD2** I've found a mistake in my code, it needs to be

```
// Get the detailed category object
    $category = get_category($cat);
    $cat_parent_id = $category->category_parent;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend against using a 404, as that implies something different, and specific; the content is not there or is unavailable, not the content is a child of this taxonomy.

BUT, if you wanted to..... Just copy the code from your 404.php and nest it in a conditional statement that queries the category + 1 level down. Something like this:

> if( is_category('Catalog') ){
>       $this_category = get_queried_object();
>       if( 0 != $this_category->parent ){
>           // code from 404.php
>       } }